# Print multipaged WPF control without page breaking on a line of data C#

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, page-break, multipage

I made an invoice that has a listview on the bottom to list all of the line items. This can run over the one page mark so I overloaded the  DocumentPaginator  class to allow for me to print multiple pages. However, sometimes it cuts the page in the middle of a line of the listview. I found an article that uses a bitmap of the wpf control, then checks the color of pixels of a line to determine if there is whitespace or data (code below). When I make my control into a bitmap though, the spacing and line height is different than when I print the wpf control as an xps or to the printer. Any other ideas out there on how to intelligently break pages or get the bitmap to match the xps?

```
 private void GetGoodCut()
    {
        int goodCut = _lastCut; 
        int lastNumber = 0;
        int numberCount = 1;
        // At most, it will take 32 pixel lines to find a white space
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            int number = rowPixelWhiteCount(_bitmap, goodCut);
            goodCut--;

            if (number == lastNumber)
            {
                numberCount++;
                // White space count between LV lines is 12 
                if (numberCount == 12)
                {
                    lastNumber = i - 6;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // If we started inside a white space, can break if starting before/at middle of the white space
                if (numberCount > 5)
                {
                    lastNumber = i - 6;
                    break;
                }
                numberCount = 1;
            }

            lastNumber = number;
        }

        _lastCut -= lastNumber;
    }

 private int rowPixelWhiteCount(System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp, int row)
    {
        int colorCount = 0;
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
        int stride = bmpData.Stride;
        IntPtr firstPixelInImage = bmpData.Scan0;

        unsafe
        {
            byte* p = (byte*)(void*)firstPixelInImage;
            p += stride * row;  // find starting pixel of the specified row
            for (int column = 0; column < bmp.Width; column++)
            {
                // Printing in black/white, look for non-black pixels
                byte blue = p[0];
                byte red = p[1];
                byte green = p[3];
                if (blue > 0 && red > 0 && green > 0)
                    colorCount++;

                // go to next pixel
                p += 3;
            }
        }
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        count.Add(colorCount);

        return colorCount;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the secret to printing multiple pages from a WPF Application is to use multiple `FixedDocument` elements... you can also use your `DocumentPaginator` element in this process. As this is well documented online, I won't go over it all again here. Instead, please refer to the [WPF Printing Part 2 – The Fixed Document](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/20/wpf-printing-part-2-the-fixed-document.aspx) page on the NBD Tech website for the full story.

As additional help, you can also refer to the [Advanced WPF Part 2 of 5: Printing in Windows Presentation Foundation](http://www.abhishekshukla.com/wpf/advanced-wpf-part-2-printing-in-windows-presentation-foundation/) page on Abhishek Shukla's website.

Finally, if all else fails, you might be interested in using the code from the [WPF Print Engine: Part I](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238135/WPF-Print-Engine-Part-I) page on Code Project.

Comment: The first two links didn't mention anything about page breaks. The last link gave me the idea to switch out my  ListView  out for a  DataGrid  , which doesn't look as good, but it does manage itself on page breaks. However, on a different form i'm printing, has a dynamic  ListView  on it that cannot be changed into a  DataGrid  . So still looking for an answer.